# PHPUnit: setUpBeforeClass and tearDownAfterClass is not working

Tags: php, phpunit

In my test cases, I have extend my test case class to another base class, where I have used `setUp` to set the global variables. I have extended this base class to child class where I have written test cases. Now, I have many child test classes which extends this base class. That's why, rather than using `setUp` in each child class, I have used only in base class.

This is my setup:

1. Base Class

   ```
   use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

   class BaseClass extends TestCase
   {
       public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
           //global vars setup
       }

       public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
           //global vars teardown
       }
   }
   ```
2. Child Class

   ```
   class ChildClass extends BaseClass
   {
       public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
           //setup some other stuff related to only this child class 
           parent::setUpBeforeClass();
       }

       public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
           //teardown some other stuff related to only this child class 
           parent::tearDownAfterClass();
       }
   }
   ```

Now, I want to use PHPUnit's `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass` in my child classes to do some other stuff which is only related to only this child class.

But it is not working. After running tests, PHPUnit stops suddenly without throwing any errors. Kindly guide me here.

Comment: The methods `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass` need to be static methods

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for highlighting. But still it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you explain us how you initialize and launch your test ? (Have you a bootstrap file ?)

Comment: I have bootstrap file, but it has nothing in that(only one file included and few error generation code). I couldn't exactly understand what you mean by initialize and launch.